# TypeScript: inferring data types from variadic tuple types

Tags: typescript, types, tuples, variadic-functions

Variadic tuple types allow us to provide the caller of a function, a tuple return type
*driven by the tuple supplied* to the function like so:

```
function makeArrayAsConstItems<T extends readonly any[]>(...arr: [...T]): {[K in keyof T]: {item: T[K]} } {
    return arr.map(item => ({ item })) as any;
}

const arrayAsConstItems = makeArrayAsConstItems('cfgh', 1, new Date());

// this is the type
const arrayAsConstItems: [{
    item: string;
}, {
    item: number;
}, {
    item: Date;
}]
```

Now consider we want to do two more things:

1. Narrow the items that can be supplied in each array element to be a type of `Data<TypeOfData>`
2. Extract the type we're going to be returning from `Data<TypeOfData>`; so use `TypeOfData` essentially

```
interface Data<TypeOfData = unknown> {
    data: TypeOfData;
}

function makeArrayAsConstItemsForDataTypesOnly<T extends readonly Data[]>(...arr: [...T]): {[K in keyof T]: {item: T[K]} } {
    return arr.map(item => ({ item })) as any;
}

const arrayAsConstItemsForDataTypesOnly = makeArrayAsConstItemsForDataTypesOnly(
    { data: 'cfgh' }, 
    { data: 1 }, 
    { data: new Date() }
)
```

What would we need to do for `arrayAsConstItemsForDataTypesOnly` to have the same type as `arrayAsConstItems`?

At present the type is:

```
const arrayAsConstItemsForDataTypesOnly: [{
    item: {
        data: string;
    };
}, {
    item: {
        data: number;
    };
}, {
    item: {
        data: Date;
    };
}]
```

And we desire it to be:

```
const arrayAsConstItemsForDataTypesOnly: [{
    item: string;
}, {
    item: number;
}, {
    item: Date;
}]
```

---

This is @A_blop's suggestion:

```
function makeArrayAsConstItemsForDataTypesOnly<T extends readonly Data[]>(...arr: [...T]): {[K in keyof T]: {item: Extract<T[K], Data>["data"]} } {
    return arr.map(item => ({ item })) as any;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried `{[K in keyof T]: {item: Extract<T[K], Data>["data"]} }` ?

Comment: that works! Do you want to add it as an answer and I'll accept?

Comment: sure, thanks. Have added an answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can do that by utilizing [lookup types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-1.html#keyof-and-lookup-types) in combination with the `Extract` [utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#extracttype-union):

```
function fn<T extends readonly Data[]>(...arr: [...T]):
    { [K in keyof T]: { item: Extract<T[K], Data>["data"] } } {/* impl */}
```

```
const arrayAsConstItemsForDataTypesOnly = fn(
    { data: 'cfgh' },
    { data: 1 },
    { data: new Date() }
)
/*
[{
    item: string;
}, {
    item: number;
}, {
    item: Date;
}]
 */
```

As TypeScript cannot resolve `T[K]` further, we need to first convince it again, that the resulting type has a `data` property accessible via lookup operator. This is done by `Extract`.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCJzHAPAFQJ4AOEA8jOpsgLzICuIA1iAPYDuIAfMgN4BQy-yACYY4ALmT4ipcnADcPAL48eMOgjDAmIZDBC5kEAB6QQggM7IoEOIK0AbPGhEBtALrsAFADofcKFHFnHy8cVwBKUT4BLmRnAGlkUGR6CDwmGAlXcRjgSABbcQBRYyhEMFx41wAaJ0x2ZwAiYUwG12QFdu4o-iswGihtPygvPLgCD1yIPKpODxz89rCw5DgLOBA8eSUeBC0zMBX-ODwAQTMAYT2wAEl8swAxJigZSQgzYhAHKh0QD27uIQicQAcgQMAA5gALYHtKr-GLNMTIACMsPhgMw4hAEBYtQgHmWSjCPAA9AAqHjOXgCRL5cT7KCgcFbGrUgSTArIEA0PIAI2gLK6NI54nIEC2rj4ZJJQA)

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer @A_blop!  Just what I needed; in case you're curious, the motivation was working on this: https://github.com/tannerlinsley/react-query/pull/1527#issuecomment-753648710